# Microsoft Test Manager - An error occurred with the diagnostic data adapter IntelliTrace

Tags: iis, intellitrace, microsoft-test-manager

I get the following error message when I attempt to run a test in Microsoft Test Manager.

> This adapter will not be used for this
>   test run.  The following error
>   occurred: The element 'StartupInfo' in
>   namespace
>   'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:visualstudio:tracelog'
>   has invalid child element
>   'DeleteLogOnClose' in namespace
>   'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:visualstudio:tracelog'.

Looking in the event log on the (agent and controller - same box) server I see the following error shortly before the above one:

> (QTDCAgent32.exe, PID 2700, Thread 7)
>   Data collector
>   'datacollector://microsoft/TestImpact/1.0'
>   logged the following error: This
>   adapter will not be used for this test
>   run.  The following error occurred:
>   Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

I've searched for a solution but cannot find anyone else who encountered this issue.

Anyone have any ideas?? I'm getting desperate!

Thanks

JP

Answer (score 0):

For at least the first error it looks like you have an invalid Collection Plan. Have you modified them at all? Did you change Visual Studio versions at all?

Check both:

Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector.dll.config and
Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\TraceDebugger Tools\en\CollectionPlan.xml

I would at least try removing that node 'DeleteLogOnClose' altogther to start with.

Comment: Hi Luke, I haven't modified my collection plan and I have two different PCs - one with VS, the other with MTM - both getting the same error when connecting to the same server. I looked at both files (on the MTM box at least) and do not see DeleteLogOnClose anywhere...

Comment: I believe the MTM test settings can include collection plan settings. If you have upgraded from Dev10 to Dev10SP1 and use the same test settings, try deleting the test settings file and re-creating a new one. That will ensure it has the correct SP1 collection plan.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with VS 2010. I was able to resolve it by applying vs 2010 sp1.